# What happens if you connect a memory stick with invalid file names to Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, filenames, memorystick

Windows has some forbidden filenames such as "con", and filenames with backslashes ("\") are also not allowed (as the backslash is used to separate folders in paths) nor can the same folder have a files where capitalization is the only thing that separates them (so you cannot have a file named "file" and another named "File" in the same folders on Windows). So what happens if you create a file or files breaking those rules (e.g. using a Linux or a Mac) and save them to a memory stick and connect that to Windows?

In theory, I could easily test that myself, but I don't want to as I'm not sure if it's safe, and to my surprise, I wasn't able to find the answer by googling either.

Comment: "In theory, I could easily test that myself, but…" – In practice a virtual machine with Windows might come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

There will be no problem, Windows will show the files with :
- their original name for case-only differences (e.g file / File will show both correctly)
- a converted name (e.g. 'file\one' shows as 'FYGTM9~3' in windows).

Anyway, no issue or risk neither for windows or for the stick itself.

Indeed, a virtual machine running Windows is a good practice for any testing purpose.

Comment: OK, now I tested it myself. What happened was that Linux wasn't able to save files with backslashes. After "file" was saved, I told Python to write a file called "File", and what happened was that the contents of "file" was replaced with the one I asked to be written to "File", but no "File" appeared in the folder. "con.txt" was successfully written by Linux. When I connected the stick to Windows, it said it had a problem and asked if I want Windows to try to repair it. I said no ("continue without checking"), after which Windows did show that it exists, but it was unable to open or delete it.

Comment: (The memory stick in question was an old Kingston with 512 MB storage, if that's relevant)

Comment: "Kingston with 512 MB" a piece of computer history, I still have my first flash drive, a Lexar 64MB and works like a champ.

Comment: Yes, you can save files with backslashes in Linux, you just need to escape it using another \. For example,  type 'echo "this is some text" > my\\file' and you'll get my\file...

Comment: Sure, I just meant that writing a file like that onto the memory stick was not possible. Onto the hard drive I sure can do that.